# How do I get my XP laptop to connect with Wireless N, WAP set to 11b/g/n mixed mode?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I'm trying to get my wireless XP Pro laptop to connect to my wireless access point / ADSL modem at the faster Wireless N speed.

My WAP is set to 11b/g/n mixed mode, so I think that means that it provides wireless N.

My connection is at a maximum of 54 Mbps.

I can't see any options to increase the speed ?

Comment: And can your wireless network card in the laptop provide N-Wireless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove any 802.11g devices from your network, the connection may be downgrading for another device that cannot handle 802.11n.

However, if you're using the wireless connection only to access the web, it is very unlikely your WAN connection (in this case, your DSL line) is faster than 54 mb/s, thus the benefits of using 802.11n speeds for your LAN are minimal. It is quite possible that no gains in speed would be apparent.